# Django Saving Form Instance to a Different Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to save the instance of the form to a different database.

Usually when executing a save on an object instance you will use `object.save(using='db_alias')`, which I assumed would be for the `form.save()` function.

Currently I am using...

`form.save(using='db_alias')`

This throws an error claiming `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'`.

Do I need to override the `save()` function within this particular form to handle a `db_alias` argument? I wasn't able to find anything regarding this error when searching, so I am asking here as last resort for the best foot forward. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right , you can't save form such way, but you can use `commit=False` and then save the instance, for example:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.save(using='db_alias')
```

Comment: Oh wow. Alright then I like this. I will try it as soon as I can and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You have to run makemigrations --database= to populate tables into the said db I order for instance = form.save(commit=False); instance.save(using=) to work.